# Using getline(cin, var) twice produces error when doing string comparison (==)

Tags: c++, getline

```
void command_menu(){
  string command = "default000",
         command_upper;
  bool incorrect_input = false;
  do{
    clear_replit();
    default_display();
    cout << "\nType 'commands' to see a list of options, or enter a command.\n";
    if(command == "default000"){}
    else{
      cout << special_text("red","'");
      cout << special_text("green", command) << special_text("red", "'");
      cout << special_text("red", " is not a recognized command.\n");
    }
    getline(cin, command);
    command_upper = string_toupper(command);
    if(command_upper == "COMMANDS"){
      list_of_commands();
    }
```

I'm having a problem getting this snippet of code to work which hasn't been resolved by adding cin.ignore() or cin.clear() or both before or after the getline command.

If I type in "commands" at the prompt, the if(command = "commands") check passes. If I first type in gibberish ("blah"), I get re-prompted as expected, and if I enter "commands" it does store the word "commands" in the getline variable, but now the if(command == "commands") check fails.

If you need a working code, my entire project can be found here:
https://repl.it/@AndreLouis/Scrabble#main.cpp

Reproduce the error by first typing "commands" and seeing the program execute, then run the program again, type "blah", and then type "commands".

Comment: It will be helpful to see a [mcve]. It's hard telling where the problem could be by looking at the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `incorrect_input` value.
When you compare `command_upper` to *"COMMANDS"* you need to make sure to set that variable to *false*, otherwise after the first failed check, the value will always be *true*

Set `incorrect_input` fo false at the start of the loop:

```
bool incorrect_input = false;
do{
    incorrect_input = false;
    clear_replit();
...
```

Comment: I feel like it would be better to declare incorrect_input = false; at the start of the loop, and only after it doesn't satisfy all the if conditions then we set it to true.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's nothing wrong with getline, the error was with where I declared my boolean value. I overlooked that because I've struggled with the nuances of cin and getline before. Thank you Rafael!

Comment: @DesmondCheong I wanted to be clear about the issue, but I agree that doing that at the start of the loop is better, I fixed the answer.